# Can a bluetooth usb device be programmed (frequency reception) to play FM radio

Tags: bluetooth, radio

The title is the question - Can a bluetooth usb device be programmed (frequency reception) to play FM radio? If yes how would one do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Bluetooth operates at 2,4 GHz (that is 2400 MHz) whereas FM radios operate between 86 and 108 MHz. The antennes and high frequency circuits are complete different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would a USB FM radio device work and are such devices available?

Comment: USB FM radio receiver should work, although I have never used them myself. You may search "USB radio receiver" on eBay or Amazon, they look like a big USB memory stick with attached antenne. Check compatiblity to your operating system and whether it can receive your local FM frequencies (there are minor differences between Europe, America and Japan).